# Output of getPaymentHtml() in Magento

Tags: magento

I haven't been able to find where does the output of `getPaymentHtml()` comes from.

Its defined as:

`public function getPaymentHtml() {
    return $this->getChildHtml('payment_info');
}`

I couldn't find out the template for `payment_info` block.

Basically I want to be able to retrieve credit card type and credit card number in the progress block of checkout.

How do I find out the method names? Something like `$this->getCreditCardType()`

Edit: OK! I understand that Magento figures out the payment method first which has their corresponding templates which are used to render output. But in `progress.phtml` of checkout, `var_dump( $this instanceof Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cc );` returns false, so how do I access that in current context?

Comment: If you want to get class name of the current payment info block from progress.phtml try this code `$info = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment();
if ($method = $info->getMethod()) {
    $modelClass = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$method.'/model');
    $blockType = Mage::getModel($modelClass)->getInfoBlockType();
    echo get_class($this->getLayout()->createBlock($blockType));
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Progress block doen't have it's own template for Payment info.  Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Info block uses the selected Payment Method block to output html. Look at the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Info::_toHtml()` method:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $html = '';
    if ($block = $this->getChild($this->_getInfoBlockName())) {
        $html = $block->toHtml();
    }
    return $html;
}
```

To find the actual template and block for the specific Payment method you use, you need to perform next steps:

1. First - get model alias for current payment method `Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$yourMethod.'/model')` and instantiate it using `Mage::getModel(alias)`
2. then get block type using $model->getInfoBlockType() - so you'll be able to find the actual Block by it's type

For example for **ccSave** payment method the info block is Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Ccsave, and template for it is app\design\frontend\base\default\template\payment\info\default.phtml. You'll be able to find all data inside those.
Good luck ;)

For the sake of completeness, exact functions to fetch CC type and last 4 digits of CC number are:

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCcType();
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCcLast4();
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand whats going on here now. Can you look at my edit?

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation was quicker to follow for a less experienced Magento developer. Upvoted & accepted!

Answer (score 1):

The block class is declared in layout update XML; see the [onepage checkout](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml#L350) and [multishipping](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml#L271) directives from *checkout.xml*. The actual child block which is used depends on the payment model which is being used, but there is a common template that will be used unless overridden.

Example:

- See the generic CC method model [`Mage_Payment_ModelMethod_Cc`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php#L31)
- From that see its info block [`Mage_Payent_Block_Info_Cc`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Cc.php)...
- ...which will lead you to the "base" payment info block [`Mage_Payment_Block_Info`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info.php) which [sets a default template](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info.php#L43).

Comment: Thank you Sir! It makes sense now, but missing something obvious. Can you look at my edit?